# Find the level of confidence given that standard deviation is 12 and there is sample size of 16:

Tags: probability, statistics, confidence-interval

A confidence interval for the mean price shows a $9.30 margin of error. What was the level of confidence?
A. 99.9%
B. 99.8%
C. 99.7%
D. 99.6%
E. 99.5%

I know that z(a/2) (std dev)/(sqrt n)=9.3

z(a/2)=3.1

And the corresponding z score is 0.9987, but I am struggling because of the (a/2), and I feel like an extra step is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer is **Option B: 99.8%** Below is the explanation in the image.

Standard deviation $\sigma=\$12$, $n=16$, $E=\$9.30$

\begin{align*}
E=Z_{\alpha/2}\cdot\frac\sigma{\sqrt n}
&\implies 9.30=Z_{\alpha/2}\cdot\frac{12}{\sqrt{16}}
\\
&\implies Z_{\alpha/2}=9.30/3=3.10
\end{align*}

As
$$P(2<3.10)=0.9990\implies\alpha/2=1-0.9990=0.001$$
it follows that $\underline{\alpha=0.002}$. So, for the level of confidence $c$
$$c=1-\alpha=1-0.002=0.998\,\therefore\, c=99.8\%$$

Comment: Please don't use image only posts. [Here's is MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I'm new to math exchange portal so posted the solution in image. In my next answers I'll be using the tool. Thanks for letting me know

Comment: I've edited your answer using MathJax. Make sure that everything is still correct and take a look at the code to see how the basics work.

Comment: All good.. Thanks mate